# Send and recieve variable from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, communication

This may be a very simple question, but I'm new to python and haven't been able to figure it out.

I want to do something very simple: call a subprocess and send to it two variables at the start (eg: G=[0,1] and K=3), that it needs to run. From the subprocess I want to receive back a list of values in my original script.

I manage to get it to run without any problems:

```
    os.system('abaqus cae noGUI=E11_1')
```

...but the sending and receiving values I can not figure out. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

For anyone seeing this and also working on abaqus like me. To get interact with an abaqus script you need to use the "abaqus python" module (instead of "abaqus CAE"). By coding like this:

```
    os.system('abaqus python script.py var1 var2')
```

you will send var1 and var2 (as string) to script.py. There you can access the variables with

```
    v1 = int(sys.argv[1])   (= var1)
    v2 = int(sys.argv[2])   (= var2)
```

In the python.py script you can access an .odb with:

```
    odb = openOdb(path+odbname+'.odb')
```

and do whichever operations you want.

I hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.